# Titanium underscore adding removing items from array

Tags: arrays, listview, titanium, underscore.js

i am using titanium 3.3 and alloy 1.4.1. the user should be able to send an email to all selected people (those people are in an array called "contacts") from his phone's address book.

the user can select and deselect names/emails from his addressbook in a listview (yellow background in the linked screenshot).

screenshot:
http://s30.postimg.org/rsa82u9qp/listview_checkbox.png

the correct info (email) is pulled from the address book and added to the contacts array when one checks the checkbox. so selecting via the checkbox works, but when one deselects the checkbox the email/item is not removed from the array. see the last log entry line:

> Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(contacts) + " this is matches array at the
>   end");

the email which has been selected before and is now deselected is still in the contacts array.

i also found this, but it doesnt help unfortunately.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/163878/loop-through-listview-to-grab-items-with-certain-properties#comment-206400

the code:

```
$.listview.addEventListener('itemclick',function(e){
var item = e.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
if (item.properties.accessoryType == Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE) {
    item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_CHECKMARK;
    Ti.API.info(item.textEmail.text + " this is item.textEmail.textinside adding if");   
    var added = item.textEmail.text;
    if (!_.contains(contacts,added)) {contacts.push(added);
}
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(added) + " item 1 added");   
    Ti.API.info(contacts + " this is matches array inside adding if");
}
else {
    item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE;
    var removed = item.textEmail.text;
   contacts = _.without(contacts, removed); 
    //contacts.splice(removed);
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(removed) + " item 2 removed");
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(contacts) + " this is contacts in removing if case");
}
e.section.updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, item); 
Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(contacts) + " this is matches array at the end");
});
```

any ideas what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should have a flat Array (contacts):

```
var contacts = new Array();
```

...

Then add/remove textEmail.text properties and search them properly

```
if (item.properties.accessoryType == Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE)
{
    item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_CHECKMARK;
    var i;
    for(i in item.textEmail.text) //item.textEmail.text is Object
    {
       if(contacts.indexOf(item.textEmail.text[i]) === -1)
       {
          contacts.push(item.textEmail.text[i]);
          Ti.API.info(item.textEmail.text[i] + " item added");  
       }
    }
    Ti.API.info(contacts + " this is matches array inside adding if");
}
else
{
    item.properties.accessoryType = Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE;
    var i;
    for(i in item.textEmail.text)
    {
       var p = contacts.indexOf(item.textEmail.text[i]);
       if(p !== -1)
       {
          contacts.splice(p,1);
          Ti.API.info(item.textEmail.text[i] + " item removed");
       }
    }
    Ti.API.info(contacts + " this is contacts in removing if case");
}
```

// if item.textEmail.text is equal to Email Person Object:
{ "work" : ["...", "..."], "home" : ["...", "..."] }

```
var i, j;

for(i in item.textEmail.text)
{
    for(j = 0; j < item.textEmail.text[i].length; j++)
    {
       // Start Add Code
       if(contacts.indexOf(item.textEmail.text[i][j]) === -1)
       {
          contacts.push(item.textEmail.text[i]);
       } // End Add Code

       // Start Remove Code
       var p = contacts.indexOf(item.textEmail.text[i]);
       if(p !== -1)
       {
          contacts.splice(p,1);
       } // End Remove Code
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, many thanks for your fast reply. ive tried the snippet you posted - it removes items now, but not the correct ones. i also saw that the email field (item.textEmail.text) is a multiple value field (some have home and email addresses). i checked and the original code works (including the removal function) with the (single value) "recordID" and "fullName" fields.

Comment: Splice return the removed element, sorry for this little detail.

Comment: I have seen at this link [Person](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts.Person-property-email) that email is a Object with Array String Values, so you should be change the iterations for double iterations. I have changed my answer ;)

Comment: hola Alejandro! You are the official hero for the day for me! works like a charm. muchas gracias!